# IllegalArgumentException while running contract unit test in Kotlin (Corda)

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, corda

When I try to run my Junit tests (Wrote in Kotlin) I get the following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempted to find dependent attachment for class javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter, but could not find a suitable candidate.
```

I tried to comment/decomment some lines in following code, it seems that the exception occurs when I call command()

class IRIssueTests {

```
class DummyCommand : TypeOnlyCommandData()

private val ledgerServices = MockServices(listOf("com.my.package.name"))

private val ALICE = TestIdentity(CordaX500Name(organisation = "Alice", locality = "TestLand", country = "US"))

@Test
fun mustIncludeIssueCommand() {
    val ir = IRState(
        UniqueIdentifier(),
        mutableListOf(ALICE.party)
    )

    ledgerServices.ledger {
        transaction {
            output(IRContract.ID, ir)
            command(listOf(ALICE.publicKey), DummyCommand())
            fails()
        }
        transaction {
            output(IRContract.ID, ir)
            command(listOf(ALICE.publicKey), IRContract.Commands.Issue())
            verifies()
        }
    }
}
```

}

I would like to understand why I'm getting this exception and how to resolve it to make my test passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin tests must be run with JDK8. 
Change configuration of JDK8 in your project before running tests.
This will avoid this exception